# Why does Python 3 print end "" produce an exception in the interpreter but not from import?

Tags: python

In Python 3, this works when importing from a file:

```
myInt = 0
while (myInt < 10):
    print (myInt, end='')
    myInt += 1
print (' are Numerals.')
```

producing the expected result: "0123456789 are Numerals."

But if the code is pasted directly into an interpreter, the last line produces an exception. In fact, anything after the while block exits does:

```
    File "<stdin>", line 4
    print (' are  Numerals.')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[The following is a reply to François in the form of focusing the question.]

It doesn't work in Python 2 using the trailing `","` construct either...

Adding a blank line after the while block doesn't work as it clearly won't produce the desired result, namely "0123456789 are Numerals." 
Taking Jean-François' lead, however, this produces a similar result:

```
myInt = 0
res=""
while (myInt < 10):
    res += str (myInt)
    myInt += 1

res += ' are my Numerals.'
print (res)
```

But is there any way of forcing the end of the while block in the interpreter which would allow printing (or string compilation, or whatever) to continue?
Well, I can produce the result, when I use else and enter the following, a line at a time:

```
>>> myInt = 0
>>> while (myInt < 10):
...     print (myInt, end='')
...     myInt += 1
... else:
...     print (' are Numerals.')
... 
0123456789 are Numerals.
```

but when I copy/paste the whole code into the interpreter, the exception is raised. So what is the difference between copy-pasting into the interpreter and typing it a line at a time? I'm even more curious now!

Comment: EDIT: Nevernind, the space doesn't matter. Delete the space between the print and the (. it should be `print(' are numerals.'`)

Comment: The space shouldn't matter. The lexer will take care of that.

Comment: I don't get an error running this, but yea the space shouldn't matter.

Comment: @user3483203 I get an error on repl python2 (that's probably OP's issue)

Comment: Are you sure your interpreter is Python 3?

Comment: Mine is Python3, and I reproduced the error.  It acts as if it wants a blank line to terminate the `while` loop.  Simple out-denting gets the syntax error.  Continuing with another indented statement defers the error until I out-dent.

Comment: Good question, but it's a bad idea to try to create loops and stuff with the command line interpreter anyway.

Comment: Adding a blank line after the while block doesn't work as it clearly won't produce the desires result, namely "0123456789 are Numerals."

Answer (score 10):

The interpreter expects input in a very specific form for multi-line statements. You can see that by inputting the lines one at a time.

```
>>> myInt = 0
>>> while (myInt < 10):
...  print (myInt, end='')
...  myInt += 1
... print (' are Numerals')
```

After a multi-line statement, the interpreter expects a blank line to signify the end of the block. When it encounters a new, un-indented statement immediately, it's confused.

Adding a blank line after the end of the `while` loop will allow the interpreter to understand your block. Remember that the Python interpreter always runs one statement at a time. When you copy-paste multiple lines, you're really running them as completely separate statements, and in the interpreter, a multi-line statement has to be terminated by a newline.